# Let $S$ be the subspace of $\mathbb ℝ^3$ spanned by $\bf u$ and $\bf v$. Find the closest point $p$ in $S$ to the point $w$.

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $S$ be the subspace of $\mathbb ℝ^3$ spanned by vectors $\bf u$ and $\bf v$. Find the closest point $p$ in $S$ to the point $w$, given:

$\bf u^T$ = $[1,-2,2]$

$\bf v^T$ = $[-4,-7,-5]$

$w^T$ = $[3,3,1].$

Does anyone know how to do it? Step by step would be helpful as I have a ton of these questions. Thanks a lot!

Comment: P is the projection of W onto S. Do you know how to compute a projection? If not, I can provide a more detailed answer.

Comment: @Alex help would be very much appreciated

Comment: write $p = ku + lv$ as a linear combination of $u$ and $v.$ determine $k$ and $l$ by constraining $w - p$ to be orthogonal to $u$ and $w.$ you will be able to form two linear equations for $k$ and $l.$ solve that system of two linear equations.

Answer (score 2):

Here you have to remember that the projection over a subspace is the sum of the projections onto the vectors that span the subspace. Meaning this:
$$\mathrm{proj}_{S}w = \mathrm{proj}_u w + \mathrm{proj}_v w \\ \mathrm{proj}_S w = \frac{\langle w, u \rangle}{\langle u, u \rangle}u + \frac{\langle w, v \rangle}{\langle v, v \rangle}v$$

Remember that all of this depends on the inner product that you're using. I assume that in this case is $\langle \left(x_1, y_1, z_1\right), \left(x_2, y_2, z_2 \right) \rangle = \sum_{i = 0}^3 x_i y_i$.
An easy way to remember the expression for the projection is to see that the vector that appears the most, is the one that gives the final direction (in $\mathrm{proj}_v w$, $v$ will appear the most, for instance).
Can you do the calculations now?