# Find the closest point to a subspace, exercise verification...

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification

Let $S = \{x \in \Bbb{R}^3 : 2x_1 + 2x_2 -x_3 = 0\}$ be a subspace of $\Bbb{R}^3$ with the usual inner product. Find the closest point to $(2,-2,3)$.

Im assuming, from post [Let $S$ be the subspace of $\mathbb ℝ^3$ spanned by $\bf u$ and $\bf v$. Find the closest point $p$ in $S$ to the point $w$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/735887/let-s-be-the-subspace-of-mathbb-%E2%84%9D3-spanned-by-bf-u-and-bf-v-find-th?rq=1) , that I need to compute
$$ \mathrm{proj}_S w = \frac{\langle w, u \rangle}{\langle u, u \rangle}u + \frac{\langle w, v \rangle}{\langle v, v \rangle}v.$$

**My solution**:
$ 2x_1 + 2x_2 -x_3 = 0 $ implies $<(2,2,-1),(x_1,x_2,x_3)> = 0$ with $(2,2,-1)$ a normal vector tothe plane where $(x_1,x_2,x_3)$ lives. So I proposed to find 2 normal vectors to $(2,2,-1)$ which are linearly independent form each other, and that span $S$. I chose $$u = (1, -1, 0) \\ v=(0,1,2)$$.

Making the computations for $\mathrm{proj}_S w = \frac{\langle w, u \rangle}{\langle u, u \rangle}u + \frac{\langle w, v \rangle}{\langle v, v \rangle}v$

I get $$ \mathrm{proj}_S w = (2, -2, 0) + (0, \frac{4}{5}, \frac{8}{5}) = (2, \frac{6}{5}, \frac{8}{5})$$. So $(2, \frac{6}{5}, \frac{8}{5})$ is the point in $S$ I am looking for.

Is this whole reasoning ok, or did I make some huge mistake which I am not aware of? Thanks in advance for the help

Comment: That point is not on $S$.

Comment: A simpler way to compute the projection onto $S$ is to compute the projection onto its normal and subtract.

Comment: It’s not enough for the basis vectors to be linearly independent for the projection onto $S$ to equal the sum of the individual projections. They must also be orthogonal. See https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1882061/265466.

Comment: @amd It only has to be an orthogonal basis, or orthonormal too? (I did not understand the first suggestion very well)

Comment: The formula for orthogonal projection includes normalization in the denominator, so the basis need not be orthonormal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a simple method to find the nearest point on the hyperplane
with equation
$$\mathbf{a}\cdot\mathbf{r}=c\tag1$$
to a point $\mathbf{b}\in\Bbb R^n$. This point is
$$\mathbf{x}=\mathbf{b}+\lambda\mathbf{a}\tag2$$
for some $\lambda$. Putting $\mathbf{r}=\mathbf{x}$ in (1) gives
$$\lambda=\frac{c-\mathbf{a}\cdot\mathbf{b}}{|\mathbf{a}|^2}.$$
Finally, insert this value of $\lambda$ into (2).